# Json.NET decimal serialisation issue

Tags: c#, decimal, json.net

If I have a decimal that represents some Japanese Yen (i.e. exponent zero currency) amount e.g. 3131313, I see Json.NET serialising the value to 3131313.0 by default.

Is there any way to get it to serialise the literal value 3131313 instead?

Answer (score 1):

By implementing your own converter you can serialize as

```
var str= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
     new {s="aaa",d=(decimal)3131313},
     new MyConverter());
```

-

```
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType == typeof(decimal)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(Convert.ToInt64(value));
    }
}
```